# Why does calcHist in Opencv produce 0 array in output?

Tags: opencv

I do hist calculation using OpenCV. I have the following implementation.

```
    //Check image
    for (int i = 0; i < block.rows; i++)
    {
        unsigned char *ptr = block.ptr<unsigned char>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < block.cols; j++)
        {
            cout << (int)ptr[j] << " ";
        }   
        cout << endl;
    }

    //That gave
        240 130 176 129 96 122 192 127 240 123 112 122 64 121 80 118 128 129 224 119
160 138 176 132 144 128 144 132 64 128 64 126 16 128 16 129 112 126 64 127
128 128 96 133 240 124 240 132 96 126 32 124 144 128 144 129 176 128 144 124
0 136 112 136 80 131 64 131 16 132 48 131 0 128 224 129 240 126 144 129
16 132 240 138 160 132 64 134 16 131 112 129 208 126 0 128 16 126 176 122
208 139 176 133 176 135 240 138 176 136 80 131 128 133 192 132 64 129 144 132
32 136 176 138 224 139 224 136 80 127 160 135 144 132 64 131 192 131 48 126
80 144 192 138 16 136 192 138 240 135 112 135 32 133 208 132 32 130 64 130
144 141 144 135 48 139 32 135 32 134 112 134 80 130 160 126 144 131 96 128
80 144 208 139 112 141 16 137 96 138 48 134 0 136 96 137 32 135 192 130
208 143 224 140 64 140 240 132 224 132 96 133 160 133 96 134 0 129 96 131
128 148 144 140 128 139 96 139 32 136 48 135 80 132 96 137 0 133 240 140
208 136 96 144 64 137 144 135 16 135 16 132 0 134 160 136 128 134 128 132
240 147 176 144 160 138 176 144 176 139 160 143 224 135 128 137 96 139 160 136
176 139 144 133 240 142 192 139 112 133 112 135 208 131 208 132 128 135 48 133
32 150 0 144 128 139 0 141 64 142 32 136 16 137 112 136 16 137 48 133
128 143 0 141 48 141 192 135 128 144 16 138 80 136 192 134 16 134 160 131
0 144 144 148 16 143 48 136 144 140 144 138 160 136 192 137 80 138 160 136
16 142 32 141 192 140 160 135 32 136 192 135 192 135 240 135 48 138 0 143
208 142 96 149 160 146 208 146 32 138 192 141 112 136 208 138 96 142 160 137
128 145 64 142 16 136 0 137 144 132 32 136 96 138 48 136 240 131 208 130
48 142 128 143 128 143 160 149 208 140 16 142 176 137 208 136 240 138 0 143
192 146 160 141 112 144 96 143 112 135 224 140 96 135 176 135 80 135 128 135
48 144 224 147 0 139 48 139 128 142 224 143 0 144 80 140 16 139 192 140
0 146 160 143 176 138 160 146 240 135 128 136 176 137 192 134 192 136 112 136
208 147 16 143 80 149 112 146 224 134 16 145 48 141 224 138 128 137 112 135
64 146 0 140 192 140 0 143 208 140 96 138 128 137 176 138 208 138 48 135
64 148 224 142 16 140 64 143 112 137 64 141 64 143 224 135 80 138 80 138
240 143 240 142 64 145 0 142 208 142 128 139 0 136 240 141 48 138 80 137
64 147 32 148 112 145 80 140 64 143 112 144 0 139 112 137 176 136 80 143
48 148 64 146 144 142 160 139 176 140 0 140 144 139 32 138 80 137 112 139
208 145 192 145 96 148 240 145 128 139 16 141 80 142 224 137 16 144 208 140
240 142 96 139 176 148 16 139 96 143 16 141 32 139 176 141 48 134 192 141
128 147 64 145 80 150 112 140 112 143 240 142 96 143 224 139 192 143 144 137
0 148 80 145 128 142 48 146 160 140 32 141 192 139 16 136 176 138 16 143
48 149 80 143 80 144 112 144 64 144 208 143 96 142 192 142 240 138 48 138
192 143 48 149 176 145 176 142 64 142 160 139 16 138 128 139 64 139 192 138
192 147 224 144 64 143 64 148 0 144 96 143 32 147 208 142 64 141 224 137
112 146 208 144 96 141 64 142 208 141 112 138 144 138 80 135 16 140 176 140
208 146 96 144 112 148 112 146 112 147 192 148 16 141 32 143 224 137 80 140
128 149 96 146 224 144 32 141 240 144 112 136 192 141 64 139 96 135 144 138
160 144 80 149 208 146 96 145 128 142 64 142 64 147 208 141 144 141 16 141
48 145 192 145 32 140 176 142 0 143 96 136 160 139 80 136 192 138 96 138
32 151 224 152 208 143 112 142 0 142 144 145 176 145 0 139 240 141 32 139
112 142 0 139 176 136 64 140 128 140 64 135 64 139 128 140 64 137 96 138
128 150 0 153 32 146 208 140 80 149 240 141 240 136 224 140 160 140 32 146
240 141 160 142 192 144 208 138 112 141 144 138 128 138 48 135 176 140 16 135
96 150 176 148 80 142 224 142 16 148 208 140 240 136 224 141 32 140 144 137
192 139 0 144 64 142 144 143 32 139 192 138 160 139 208 137 80 140 96 134
48 148 192 146 16 149 0 141 144 137 32 140 192 142 176 138 240 140 16 138
80 146 144 142 80 143 192 137 224 141 176 140 80 139 128 138 64 135 144 134
160 146 208 143 160 143 0 145 112 140 224 144 208 142 80 144 0 138 144 142
144 143 48 139 32 141 0 147 16 140 0 143 176 140 128 133 176 139 160 134
176 150 240 145 64 146 144 142 96 138 240 141 128 141 112 140 128 137 160 135
176 140 128 139 224 144 160 138 208 138 224 135 48 139 208 132 160 137 96 134
208 143 112 148 0 141 96 143 96 136 32 143 176 138 240 139 160 141 176 141
176 148 176 142 112 140 16 143 96 136 80 139 240 139 144 138 160 139 160 137
96 145 32 151 224 142 96 143 48 143 96 141 112 135 48 141 240 136 80 138
80 145 0 140 64 141 48 144 32 141 208 137 80 136 192 134 32 135 16 137
64 147 48 148 240 143 208 139 112 140 240 138 176 141 32 144 64 138 64 139
160 142 208 141 160 142 48 140 208 138 80 136 160 137 48 141 224 137 96 134
64 149 48 147 32 142 80 148 176 142 192 142 208 138 48 139 112 136 64 139
144 144 96 143 240 140 240 138 160 140 0 140 0 135 208 133 32 134 192 132
80 143 0 145 128 140 48 143 208 141 96 143 96 139 192 138 0 139 112 140
96 144 80 140 64 144 32 141 192 137 32 138 176 137 80 137 80 138 0 136
64 147 144 145 208 140 64 138 144 145 224 137 48 140 0 140 96 139 192 134
64 141 208 143 128 144 80 135 192 135 112 139 176 135 128 139 144 135 128 134
80 145 32 146 80 142 64 143 192 143 176 140 224 142 112 141 32 139 144 141
96 141 64 141 240 143 224 136 48 142 160 132 192 136 160 136 64 137 32 134
224 147 192 144 96 145 16 140 192 142 128 138 0 141 0 145 176 136 96 140
128 146 16 143 160 139 176 141 192 138 208 137 48 141 160 129 96 137 144 134
112 145 32 146 208 135 240 139 240 137 192 142 176 132 96 138 144 131 16 140
64 143 112 141 112 142 0 140 160 141 0 135 240 136 224 141 112 137 64 134
160 144 80 143 160 145 192 141 96 135 80 140 240 134 224 138 48 137 176 137
64 140 80 138 0 138 64 136 48 136 128 133 16 133 224 132 80 135 224 133
224 142 16 146 80 145 224 137 144 138 160 138 160 132 64 137 112 133 0 135
224 140 80 141 0 138 112 135 0 132 144 136 240 131 112 137 208 133 0 135
16 143 32 139 32 142 160 138 96 133 128 136 112 132 16 136 176 133 112 136
96 141 0 138 96 133 176 136 112 133 176 136 240 126 0 131 16 127 80 130
112 142 160 138 0 136 16 140 192 132 48 138 64 136 176 135 208 130 160 140
```

So pixel values are there.

```
    //Histogram calculation
    int histbin = 128;//quantize
    int histSize[] = { histbin };
    float range[] = { 0, 255 };
    const float *ranges[] = { range };
    Mat  hist;
    int channels[] = { 0};
    calcHist(&block, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false);



//Print output 
    for (int h = 0; h < histbin; h++)
{
    float binVal = hist.at<float>(h);
    cout << " " << binVal;
}
```

I have outputs as follow.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: I have ran this command `cv::calcHist(&m, 1, 0, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, true, false);` and it is working fine, giving me `88` as output for given input image.